# Selenium - Why driver.quit doesn't work in the following case?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I'm writting some scripts on Selenium combined with Saucelab. However I have an issue. I do a test condition to know if I have an element or not on my page, if there is not this element I want to stop the test and send a fail flag to Saucelab.

My code is:

```
    if (len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@data-user-id='34196'][@data-shift-date='%s']/div/div[@class='shift-details']" %date))!=0 ):
    print "The shift is assigned to this user, good"
else:
    print "The shift is not assigned to this user, issue"
    sauce_client.jobs.update_job(driver.session_id, passed=False)
    driver.quit()

sauce_client.jobs.update_job(driver.session_id, passed=True)
driver.quit()
```

My problem is that `driver.quit()` in the else part doesn't work as I would like. The script is still running.

Comment: Do you get an error if the element is not found? Does it quit when it is found?

Comment: When it doesn't found the element, I see "The shift is not assigned..." on my console but the quit command seems to be ignored

Answer (score 2):

If the element cannot be found the driver throws an exception. Then the program stops.
You need to handle the exception with a try ... except block.

Read how to handle errors: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html